# Python - print seems to change value of function

Tags: python

I have a very strange problem with my Python code. I have a vector `W`, and a function called `isgood`, which takes a vector (like `W)` as input, and returns a list whose entries are strings - `'YES'` or `'NO'`. I can give more information about the function, but the problem seems to be unrelated to it.

When I go to the command line and call the value of the function, this is what I get:

```
IN [63]: isgood(W)
OUT[63]: ['YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO']
```

On the other hand, if I `print` the value of the function, I get something else:

```
IN [67]: print(isgood(W))
['NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES']
```

The value of `W` did not change between these two lines of code, and I didn't do anything between them. But somehow the two values are different.

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

Here is more information about the function:

```py
def isgood(W):
    goodlist = []
    for i in range(2, len(W), 1):
        c = switch(W[i-2])
        d = switch(W[i-1])
        if W[i]== c+d:
            goodlist.append('YES')
        else:
            goodlist.append('NO')
    return goodlist
```

Here, the input W is a list of words (which are also lists of 'A' and 'B'). The function "switch" takes a word (in this case, one of the words in W) and changes its last letter - 'A' to 'B' and 'B' to 'A'.

The function takes the list of words W, and returns a list of 'YES'/'NO', which encodes whether each word in W (except for the first two words) is 'good' or 'bad' (in the sense described above).

I won't write the input W since it contains very long words. Here is the function switch:

```py
def switch(v):
    u = v
    d = v[len(v)-1]
    if d=='A':
        u[len(u)-1] = 'B'
    else:
        u[len(u)-1] = 'A'
    return(u)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also, post [mre]. we don't know what `isgood` does or what `W` is....

Comment: @0x01010 I just made sure that I wasn't dreaming and tried printing/calling the function several times (got the same results).

Comment: @0x01010 ahem, the image (ugly as it was) said line 66, not 63. Line 63 was only introduced by your edit.

Comment: So explain it more (Like adding value of W and code of "isgood" to post) or look at @smarine's answer

Comment: what's the isgood() function ?
where's the implementation, add it to the question so that we could see what's going on.

Comment: @buran I added the function "isgood" if that helps.

Comment: *"the input W is a list of words (which are also lists of 'A' and 'B')"* - just to clarify this, a "word" here is a list (i.e. a mutable type) and not a string (an immutable type)? If so, could it be that the function `switch` mutates its input?

Comment: @slothrop That's right, a word is a list (and the entries of this list are the strings 'A' or 'B'). The function switch also returns a list of strings.

Comment: @GSofer could you show the code of that function? I have an inkling of what might be happening but can't say for sure.

Comment: @slothrop Sure, uploaded it now.

Comment: @GSofer thanks - yes, that's where the problem lies. `u = v` makes `u` refer to the same object as `v` (not to a copy of it). So your operations which modify `u` are modifying the original list. If you try `print(W)` before and after your first call to `isgood`, I think it's going to have changed.

Comment: @slothrop Man, I can't believe that was the problem... Thanks a lot! Please add this as an answer so that I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `switch` is mutating its input. (Its first line `u = v` makes the name `u` point to the same object as the input `v`, so the subsequent assignments to `u` modify that same object.)

So calling `isgood(W)` ends up changing the contents of `W`.

The behaviour seen therefore isn't related to `print` - it's that the contents of `W` aren't the same at step [67] that they were at step [63].

The easiest way to fix is likely to have `switch` operate on a copy of its input: for example, instead of `u = v`, do `u = v.copy()` or `u = v[:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what smarie has suggested in their answer, there is a possibility that there is some randomness in function `isgood()`
For instance `isgood` could be:

```
import random
def isgood(x):
    return ["YES" if random.random() > 0.5 else "NO" for i in range(len(x))]

W = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now, each call to `isgood()` would return random lists like `['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES']` or `['NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES']`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The function contains no randomness (I uploaded it to the original post). It also always returns the same values which appear above, depending on whether I use print or not.